# External USB HD issues with a twist (works on Windows7 but not XP)

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I have this older external USB HD, 160 GB.  I was using it to copy my Steam games to another computer.  On the source computer, Windows 7 64-bit, everything worked fine.  Drive reported no errors, had no hiccups, etc.

Plugging it into the Windows XP 32-bit computer, it worked fine for looking through the files, moving files around on it (no real reading/writing, just modifying the filesystem table).  However, when copying files from it to my internal HD, after a couple seconds to tens of minutes (seemingly random times), the USB device becomes unrecognized and it reports a delayed write error.

Events in system log go like this, chronologically:

(number times displayed)xSource (Event ID): "message"

> 2xdisk (51): An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk1\D during a paging operation.
>
> 1xftdisk (57): The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur.
>
> 1xApplication popup (26): Windows - Delayed Write Failed : Windows was unable to save all the data for the file E:\$Mft. The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere.
>
> 1xntfs (50): {Delayed Write Failed} Windows was unable to save all the data for the file . The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere.

These repeat for a while, then there is 10+ disk messages or ftdisk messages.

Other notes:

- This occurs on random files at random times.
- Disconnecting and reconnecting the drive maintains the unrecognized device status
- Turning off and then on fixes it.  The same files that failed will copy just fine, but it will soon fail randomly
- This problem cannot be replicated on the Windows 7 source machine when copying from the HD to a different location on its local disk
- chkdsk /f was run and found no errors.  chkdsk /f/r has the delayed write issue.
- drive was set to quick removal.  Setting to performance in device manager yielded same result
- I am not writing anything to the USB external drive, so I am not sure why there is even a delayed write error (writing file access times?)
- local Windows XP was chkdsk'd without problems
- Windows XP machine has no problems with other USB HD's
- Various USB ports were attempted
- Rebooting did not help
- Occurs with SyncToy as well as windows explorer
- SMART status is good on both local drive and the external one
- Lack of gaming is making me cranky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bad USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

First we have to find out which disk is `\Device\Harddisk1` to be absolutely sure. Use [Microsoft's guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159865) on determining physical drives from event log messages to help narrow it down. I had this issue a while back and it was caused from a bad memory module, so it's worth checking your memory with a [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) as well.

The reason it is probably working on Windows 7 and not on XP is because your XP partition may inhabit the bad sectors of the disk, while the 7 partition may not contain any.

My immediate suggestion would be to back up all data on the OS drive if you haven't already, and slap in a replacement drive.

Comment: Harddisk0 is my boot disk, Harddisk1 is my external USB drive that has 1 NTFS partition.  I am not booting from this external USB drive.  The internal OS drive reported no chkdsk errors and writes files from other external drives to it fine.